# configure: error: Could not find alsa!

Tags: linux, java, alsa, cross-compilation, openjdk

I'm trying to cross compile jdk for android. I run:

```
./configure 
--with-toolchain-path=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 
--with-sysroot=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/platforms/android-21/arch-arm 
--with-boot-jdk=$JAVA_BOOT
```

But it tells me that i need to install `libasound2-dev` wich i have installed already. How could i fix this? I installed it using: `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev`

Comment: Under what arch are you building for arch-arm ? x86_64 I presume so if you sudo apt install you install the x86_64 version od the lib when… if cross compiling for arm you need the arch arm version.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding extra paramter `--with-alsa=/usr/sbin/alsa`